# Unable to specify legend placement

Tags: r, raster

I am making a plot of a map from a raster file.  I would like my legend to be inside the plot itself instead of outside by default.  I am using this code:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(classInt)

NDII = raster("G:\\Sheyenne\\image_differencing\\NDII\\differenced.tif")
value.vector = round(values(NDII),2)
breaks.qt = classIntervals(value.vector, n = 3, style = "quantile", intervalClosure = "right")
breaks.qt = breaks.qt$brks
breaks.qt[2] = 0
xlim = c(616768.4, 646426)
ylim = c(5130933, 5159682)
print (plot(NDII, main="NDII", breaks=breaks.qt, col = rainbow(3), axes=F, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim))
legend("topright")
```

but this returns:

[image]

Comment: Since we do not have your data,  we cannot reproduce your results. However, I suspect that the color scale that you see to the right of your plot is not from `legend`.  Please try simply removing your `legend` statement and see if you get the same thing.   Your `legend` is doing nothing because you did not specify anything to be displayed.

Comment: If I remove the legend statement I do get the same thing

Comment: If you change your `legend` statement to `legend("topright", legend="ABC")`  you will see what legend is supposed to do. The color scale is coming from elsewhere in your code.

Comment: correct, I ended up plotting the legend itself using `plot(NDII, legend.only=TRUE, rainbow(3), legend.width = 1, smallplot = c(0.85,0.9, 0.35,0.65)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reproducible example

### Example with binary data

```
r <- raster(nrows = 50, ncols = 50)
set.seed(123)
id <- sample(1:2500, 100, replace = FALSE)
r[id] <- 1
plot(r)
```

[image]

Now with legend = FALSE and adding the legend after

```
plot(r, legend = FALSE, col = rev(terrain.colors(2)))
legend("topright", legend = c("Absence", "Presence"), fill = rev(terrain.colors(2)))
```

[image]

### Example with continuous data

```
r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))


plot(r, legend = FALSE, col = rev(terrain.colors(5)))
legend("topright", fill = rev(terrain.colors(5)),  legend = c("0", "20", "40", "60", "80", "100"))
```

[image]

Comment: this removed the legend all together